# jquery tabs back button support

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-bbq

I have looked around and found a couple of solutions for back button support with tabs using hash etc.

My question is this: I want to implement a page, that has a tab widget and that is called into a div using ajax.

If I click on a couple of tabs I want to be able to use the back button and page refresh and keep track of my current selected tab.  but if I go back (with the back button) far enough, I want to call the page that was loaded before the page that contains the tabs.

- **page 0** is my main page
- **page 1** is plain text and loads into a div on page0
- **page 2** has tabs and loads into that same container div

I want to be able to click page1, page2, page2-tab1, page2-tab2 and then use the back button to do a reverse.

Is this possible or are there any working examples you could point me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be `jquery BBQ` is what you are looking for, here is the link

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-jquery-ui-tabs/

also there is a stackoverflow question that is i think related to your question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin